# wvdial NO CARRIER

Tags: usb

I've been trying to connect Huawei E3131 to my Raspberry pi.
So far I've installed ppp, usb_modeswitch and wvdial. Here is my wvdial.conf partially generated by `wvdialconf` and partially changed by myself:

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Modem = /dev/modem
Username = { }
Password = { }
Baud = 9600
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0
Init3 = ATX3
Carrier Check = no
Stupid Mode = 1
Modem Type = Analog Modem
ISDN = 0
Phone = *+88690xxxxxxx#
New PPPD = yes
```

In the end the output I get looks like that:

```
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0
OK
--> Sending: ATX3
ATX3
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATDT*+88690xxxxxxx#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT*+88690xxxxxxx#
NO CARRIER
--> No Carrier!  Trying again.
--> Sending: ATDT*+88690xxxxxxx#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT*+88690xxxxxxx#
NO CARRIER
--> No Carrier!  Trying again.
```

The simcard in the dongle is from Chunghwa Telecom (Taiwan) if that is any help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, apparently you **don't** need to change the basic *99# to your phone number. So the final config file looks like

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Modem = /dev/modem
Username = { }
Password = { }
Baud = 9600
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0
Init3 = ATX3
Carrier Check = no
Stupid Mode = 1
Modem Type = Analog Modem
ISDN = 0
Phone = *99#
New PPPD = yes
```

run it with `sudo` for creation of `ppp` and everything works fine. Also you may run `wvdialconf` to generate the config file with suitable init commands. However parameteres are **not** affected by it, except Baud. Hope someone will find it useful.